# Colon (:) instead of comma when using article entry type

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I'm currently having a problem with Biblatex delimiter after the author.
I want to have `<author>: <title>` instead of `<author>, <title>`.
With the following commands it works, except when using the entry type article in my .bib-file.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
```

Has anyone faced a similar problem or can help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a small note for people with a similar question, who are not using `biblatex-ieee`: `\labelnamepunct` has been deprecated in favour of the context-sensitive `nametitledelim`, so the line would nowadays be `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}`. (Not all styles support the shift from `\labelnamepunct` to `nametitledelim` and `biblatex-ieee` supports neither. So this is not an answer to the question as posed here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ieee` style uses a simple `\setunit`. This should work:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}{\newunit
  \usebibmacro{title}}{\addcolon\space
  \usebibmacro{title}}{}{}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma is not added by `\lablenamepunct` (which btw is deprecated), but by the `\newunit` which uses `\newunitpunct`. Unfortunately this is uses in multiple places and therefore the redefinition can not be made globally but needs to be inside a group to not effect all other occurrences:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
% New bibliography drivers, using the required order of fields. These
% are mainly copied from standard.bbx then modified.
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  {\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcolon\space}\newunit}
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\makeatother

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

test

\cite{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```